# How do I reference nvmeXnYpZ partitions?

Tags: partition, macintosh, nixos, nvme

I am trying to install NixOS on my MacBook following the manual (https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-installation-partitioning-formatting) and I am stuck at the partitioning/formatting stage. After creating necessary partitions on the disk I took for NixOS (an MS-DOS partition made via Disk Utility) with `parted`, I need to initialise them as ext4 partitions and a swap partition. And in order to do that, I need to reference them.

The problem is that my NixOS disk is known as `/dev/nvme0n1p3` (p1 and p2 being ESP and OS X drive respectively) and I cannot access the reference names of the partitions I need to initialise; `gdisk` shows them correctly but `lsblk` does not count them as devices.

Is there a way to see how to reference these “sub-sub-subpartitions”?

P.S.: I am a complete newbie, this is the first time I install a Linux system so I can make real blunders in terminology etc. I apologise for this in advance.

Edit: the `lsblk` output
[image: lsblk output]

Edit 2: partition table of `nvme0n1p3` according to `gdisk`
[image: gdisk partition table]

Edit 3: so I tried to see what `fdisk` will show me, and it labels these partitions as nvme0n1p3p1, nvme0n1p3p2 and nvme0n1p3p3. Technically the question is solved, but now I cannot do anything with these partitions since all the commands involving them result in “no such file or directory” error.

Comment: Can you paste the `lsblk` output? Do you have one or 2 disks?

Comment: Nicolas, attached the lsblk output to the question (sorry for it being a picture)

Comment: Where ever your example says /dev/sdXY, you use /dev/nvme0n1pY where Y is partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not normally make nested partition tables. You seem to have created a nested partition table on nvme0n1p3, but since neither the firmware nor the Linux kernel normally look for it there, it had no effect (except potentially damaging the beginning & the end of your nvme0n1p3 partition).

Your `fdisk`/`gdisk` or any other partitioning commands should be pointed at the whole-disk device of your NVMe disk, which is `/dev/nvme0n1` in your case. The `n1` part is a *namespace identifier* which is relevant only with large enterprise NVMe storage systems: essentially all consumer-grade NVMe disks have just one namespace.

Although `/dev/nvme0` exists as a device, that will not be a block device: it’s a character device that allows access to the NVMe *controller* for certain management functions. (Install the `nvme` command line tool and run `man nvme` for more details.)

Comment: So there is no way for Linux kernel or firmware to look there for what I need? fdisk labels these partitions as nvme0n1p3pX, X being 1, 2 and 3

Comment: `fdisk` is being a bit dumb: it will create a partition table on any block device you give it, whether it makes sense or not. It will check if the name of the block device ends in a letter or a number: if number, it adds a `p` before the partition digit. You should do a `parted /dev/nvme0n1` and perhaps re-partition your current `nvme0n1p3` so that you'll get `nvme0n1p3`, `nvme0n1p4` etc. The only time you'd want to use "nvme0n1p3p1" might be if you're planning to present `nvme0n1p3` as a virtual disk for a virtual machine: the VM would see the partition as a whole disk.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the `swap` partition here at all.

Sub-partitions doesn't exist at all in `ext*` (you may encounter those in something like `ZFS` or `Btrfs` but not in `ext4`).

Except if you have really low amount of ram, you don't necessarily need a `swap` partition at all and can safely skip that step

> `gdisk` shows them correctly

Except if you've re-partitionned the disk with it and never <kbd>w</kbd>ritten the table to the disk, this is impossible (as the disk is full here)

Comment: Could you please look at the gdisk output I attached?